# Specify random effect with different variance across groups in nlme

Tags: r, mixed-models, nlme

I have a dataset with measures for individuals, where each measure represents a specific type of measure (say '1' or '2') and each individual belongs to specific group (say 'A' or 'B'). For a subset of individuals, I have observed both measures '1' and '2'. In this data, the different measures have different variances, and there is a subject-level random effect that has very different variances in the two groups. How would I go about fitting this model in the right way?

Here is an example:

```
dat <- structure(list(subject = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
                       12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
                       28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 
                       44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 
                       60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 
                       76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 
                       92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 101, 102, 102, 103, 
                       103, 104, 104, 105, 105, 106, 106, 107, 107, 108, 108, 109, 109, 
                       110, 110, 111, 111, 112, 112, 113, 113, 114, 114, 115, 115, 116, 
                       116, 117, 117, 118, 118, 119, 119, 120, 120, 121, 121, 122, 122, 
                       123, 123, 124, 124, 125, 125, 126, 126, 127, 127, 128, 128, 129, 
                       129, 130, 130), 
           group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
           measure = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
           y = c(-1.71, 
                 121.74, -1.57, 109.96, -0.64, 101.67, -0.13, 120.64, 1.47, 
                 101.99, -4.51, 133.18, -2.9, 117.95, -0.97, 126.94, -1.44, 
                 105.1, -1.52, 122.2, -2.29, 130.17, -0.35, 133.14, -0.94, 
                 112.68, -0.89, 105.37, -2.49, 126.75, -2.61, 139.25, -2.13, 
                 113.43, 0.61, 140.76, -0.75, 129.17, 1.94, 139.4, -0.49, 
                 119.03, -2.09, 89.97, -2.76, 107.85, 1.61, 136.31, -0.55, 
                 128.6, 0.41, 86.66, 0.54, 100.03, 2.46, 115.37, 6.94, 109.34, 
                 3.78, 102.34, -4.46, 104.06, 1.48, 105.06, 3.98, 85.21, 1.31, 
                 103.17, -3.35, 110.83, 2.75, 98.38, -2.43, 101.57, 2.2, 120.45, 
                 -4.06, 101.25, 3.85, 99.38, 2.17, 108, 9.27, 100.76, 3.27, 
                 110.3, 1.22, 98.91, 1.62, 105.65, 4.64, 113.07, 8.14, 108.75, 
                 6.84, 73.08, 1.42, 99.41, -0.5, 95.25, 1.42, 3.76, 102.95, 
                 85.45, -2.71, -0.48, 137.34, 114.61, -0.42, 1.71, 98.82, 
                 83.06, -3.51, -0.32, 109.66, 91.99, -0.46, -1.35, 113.88, 
                 97.32, -0.93, 1.17, 111.26, 103.9, -4.11, 6.78, 106.36, 88.22, 
                 -0.85, -6.56, 137.39, 112.19, -0.91, 3.26, 122.53, 105.18, 
                 -0.61, 4.25, 111.01, 95.85, -2.68, 3.1, 142.26, 114.44, -0.31, 
                 3.76, 127.61, 102.26, -1.82, 4.01, 116.61, 97.1, -3.61, 0.9, 
                 107.73, 90.6, -0.13, 3.78, 108.73, 95.12)), 
      row.names = c(NA, -160L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: Plot of values for the two measures across groups]

I can fit a mixed-effects model with nlme:

```
init <- c(-1.2, 120, 2, 100)

model1 <- nlme(y ~ a,
               data = dat,
               fixed = list(a ~ group : measure + 0),
               random = a ~ 1,
               groups = ~ subject,
               start = init,
               weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | measure))
```

Is there a way to fit the model such that the random effect has different variances across groups? I have a feeling that this should be achievable by using a correlation structure, but so far I have been unsuccessful.

In reality, my model is nonlinear and more complex than the above, so the problem can unfortunately not be solved by crossed random effects with `lmer` (but maybe a crossed random effects hack for nlme?)

Comment: Hmm, if the basic `nlme` fit doesn't converge without slight tweaks to the starting conditions, maybe you could try my solution below starting from a bunch of locations within the parameter space (random or hypercube or Sobol sequence or ...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following, Ben Bolker's suggestion in the comment, I ended up implementing the model in the Template Model Builder framework (Thanks for pointing me in this direction Ben!) The model did not converge for the given simulated dataset, but it did for other simulations and fitted the correct model with substantially improved likelihood values (identical to the nlme model when removing the extra variance parameter).

To achieve this, I first made the model code in `mixed.cpp`:

```
#include <TMB.hpp>

template<class Type>
Type objective_function<Type>::operator() ()
{
  // Data and design variables
  DATA_VECTOR(y); // Outcome
  DATA_ARRAY(X_mean); // Covariates
  DATA_ARRAY(X_subj); // Subject design matrix
  DATA_ARRAY(X_var); // Variance design matrix  
  DATA_ARRAY(X_var_subj); // Subject-level random-effect variance design matrix
  
  
  int n = y.size(); // Number of observations
  int n_mean = X_mean.dim[1]; // Number of observations
  int n_subj = X_subj.dim[1]; // Number of subjects
  
  
  // Parameters
  PARAMETER_VECTOR(a);  
  PARAMETER_VECTOR(a_subj);
  PARAMETER(log_sigma_measure1);
  PARAMETER(log_sigma_measure2);
  PARAMETER(log_sigma_subj_group1);
  PARAMETER(log_sigma_subj_group2);
  
  // Variance parameters
  Type sigma_measure1 = exp(log_sigma_measure1);
  Type sigma_measure2 = exp(log_sigma_measure2);
  Type sigma_subj_group1 = exp(log_sigma_subj_group1);
  Type sigma_subj_group2 = exp(log_sigma_subj_group2);
  
  // Negative log likelihood
  Type nll = 0.0;
  vector<Type> yfit(n);
  vector<Type> random(n);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // Loop over observations
    random(i) = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n_subj; j++) { // Subject random effect for observation i
      random(i) += X_subj(i, j) * a_subj(j);
    }
    
    yfit(i) = random(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < n_mean; j++) { // Mean structure for observation i
      yfit(i) += X_mean(i, j) * a(j);
    }
    
    nll += -dnorm(y(i), 
                  yfit(i),
                  X_var(i, 0) * sigma_measure1 +
                    X_var(i, 1) * sigma_measure2, true);
  }
  
  for (int j = 0; j < n_subj; j++) { // Loop over subjects for random effect contribution
    nll += -dnorm(a_subj(j), 
                  Type(0.0), 
                  X_var_subj(j, 0) * sigma_subj_group1 +
                    X_var_subj(j, 1) * sigma_subj_group2, true);
  }
  
  return nll;
}
```

and then fitted the model from R:

```
library(TMB)

compile('mixed.cpp')
dyn.load(dynlib('mixed'))

fit_dat <- list(y = dat$y, 
                X_mean = model.matrix(~ group : measure + 0, data = dat),
                X_subj = model.matrix(~ subject + 0, data = dat),
                X_var = model.matrix(~ measure + 0, data = dat),
                X_var_subj = model.matrix(~ group + 0, data = subset(dat, !duplicated(dat$subject)))

parameters <- list(a = c(-2, 120, 2, 100),
                   a_subj = rep(0, ncol(fit_dat$X_subj)),
                   log_sigma_measure1 = 0,
                   log_sigma_measure2 = 1,
                   log_sigma_subj_group1 = 2,
                   log_sigma_subj_group2 = 2) 

model <- MakeADFun(data = fit_dat, 
                   parameters = parameters,
                   DLL = 'mixed',
                   random = 'a_subj')

fit <- nlminb(start = model$par, 
              objective = model$fn, 
              gradient = model$gr)
```

So far, I am very impressed with the robustness of the `TMB` package.

Answer (score 2):

This may be tough. I can get it to work with `lme`, and I *think* I have the syntax right with `nlme`, but I'm struggling.

The basic trick is to set up a numeric dummy variable that is 0 for your baseline group and 1 for the group **with the greater among-subject variance** — this only works if you know that *a priori* (if you want to do it for lots of groups you need to identify the group with the *smallest* among-subject variance, and set up a whole bunch of group-level dummies ...)

```r
dat$groupdummy <- as.numeric(dat$group) - 1
```

Fitting the model with a diagonal RE covariance structure so it doesn't try to estimate the correlation between the baseline (group-A) among-subject RE and the 'extra' (group-B) among-subject RE, which is unidentifiable anyway ...

```r
model1 <- lme(y ~ group:measure + 0,
              data = dat,
              random = list(subject = pdDiag(~ groupdummy + 1)),
              weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | measure))
```

The answers are at least reasonable:

```r
Random effects:
 Formula: ~groupdummy + 1 | subject
 Structure: Diagonal
         (Intercept) groupdummy Residual
StdDev: 0.0002643621   11.95069 1.578527

Variance function:
 Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
 Formula: ~1 | measure 
 Parameter estimates:
       1        2 
1.000000 2.312402
```

I should warn you that you have a pretty sketchy data set as far as estimating among-subject variances goes (only 30/130 individuals have repeated measurements), and everything is going to get harder when fitting nonlinear models ...

The bad news is that I couldn't make the equivalent `nlme` model work, even fussing with control parameters. (I *think* this is the correct equivalent syntax ... although it can be hard to tell the difference between real numerical problems and incorrectly specifying the model ...)

```r
re <- ranef(model1)
names(re) <- paste0("a.",names(re))
model2 <- nlme(y ~ a,
               data = dat,
               fixed = list(a ~ group : measure + 0),
               random = pdDiag(a ~ groupdummy + 1),
               groups = ~ subject,
               start = list(fixed = fixef(model1),
                            random = re),
               control = nlmeControl(minscale = 1e-6,
                                     pnlsTol = 1e-2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to look at this Ben! The data in the post is a simulated example. I did try versions of your solution prior to posting (the real data have more than 2 groups which complicates matters), but I believe that making such a random effects design within subject is problematic because most groupdummy random effects will be predicted to be 0, which in turn decreases the estimated variance and imposes a higher regularization on the predicted random effects. With this parametrization, the model ends up assigning too much variation to 'measure' and too little to 'group'

Comment: I have spent quite some time trying to see if I could implement the desired model with `nlmer` (and other methods), but I am facing some issues with wanting to specify random effects without corresponding fixed effects. Do you have any insights into whether it may be worthwhile to spend more energy on getting `nlmer` to work, or if that seems like a dead end?

Comment: I think it might be a dead end.  I would be strongly tempted to try TMB, but I don't know what your nonlinear model is ... https://rpubs.com/bbolker/3423 ... do you really need to separate the within-subject and between-subject variation, or can you calculate averaged values for the individuals who have repeated measurements?

Comment: I was fearing that I would have to go down the model builder path. Well, I guess I will have to learn something new :-D

I'll report back once I have results (or have failed miserably)